# Custom .htaccess hidden 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to write in one rule the redirecting for each brand alias to an equivalent get-parameter? 
For example: 
"/katalog/protein/api/" must be redirected to "/katalog/protein/?ms|manufacturer=API",
"/katalog/protein/activelab/" must be redirected to "/katalog/protein/?ms|manufacturer=ActiveLab"
I'm looking for something like that in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^katalog/(protein|gainer)/(api==API|activelab==ActiveLab)/?$ /katalog/$1/?ms|manufacturer=$2 [R=301,L,QSA,NE,NC]
```

Is it possible? Thank's for any help.

Comment: Could you please add some context?

Comment: I mean: Add some information about what you are doing and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is it possible to write in one rule the redirecting for each brand alias to an equivalent get-parameter?
For example:
"/katalog/protein/api/" must be redirected to "/katalog/protein/?ms|manufacturer=API",
"/katalog/protein/activelab/" must be redirected to "/katalog/protein/?ms|manufacturer=ActiveLab". I really don't know how to explain more clearly.